# Can the network admin at work see what i browse with my work computer even if I am using a public connection, say a Hotel Wifi elsewhere?

Tags: wireless-networking, administrator, network-monitoring

I m using a laptop from work and usually I use the Wifi or ethernet at work which is definitely monitored by the office IT team/network administrators. The account I use in the laptop is a user account (not admin account). If I connect the machine to internet via an internet connection other than that at the work place (for example a restaurant Wifi), can the work place admins still track my internet activity?

Comment: If you do not own the Software AND Hardware, assume your information is effectively available to others.

Answer (score 3):

Using pure network monitoring mechanisms - no.

Using proxy monitoring, if you don't change your proxy settings - probably yes.

Using DNS request monitoring, if you don't change to some public DNS server - yes.

Using some monitoring software running on your computer - yes (or most probably yes - it depends on the implementation). Either online or it can send data when your computer is again in the work network.